# Symfony2 getDoctrine Count Results

Tags: symfony, count, doctrine

how can I output the number of results for this:

```
$count_task_done = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->findBy(array('User' => $user_id, 'Done' => TRUE));
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1 :**

At the moment I solved it in TWIG:

```
{% set count_task_done = count_task_done|length %}
```

Any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QueryBuilder for that:

```
// SeotoolMainBundle/Repository/TaskRepository.php
public function getTasksCount($user_id, $status) 
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('COUNT(t)')
        ->where('t.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('t.done = :status')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'user' => $user_id,
            'status' => $status, // true
        ));

    return $query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```